# ggplot2: classic plot with black labels for x and y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot data with a classic look and black axis labels. Yet, theme_classic has two different shades of grey for the axis tick labels and the ticks.

Using the mtcars dataset and p1 as listed in ?theme_classic I tried

```
 p1 + theme_classic(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"))
```

but this just works with theme not theme_classic.

Is there a way to get black axis ticks and labels without having to specify a classic theme from scratch?

Comment: I'd try `axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black")`

Comment: I think you have to do `p1 + theme_classic() + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="black"))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add customizations to `theme()` calls *after* `theme_classic()`. Try:

```
p1 + theme_classic() +
  theme(
    axis.text.x = element_text(color="black"),
    axis.ticks = element_line(color = "black")
  )
```

The only arguments `theme_***()` functions typically take are base size and family related arguments. Additional customization is done through plain `theme()`.